# Differential forms on the simplex which are "constant towards the boundary"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $\Delta^k$ the standard $k$-dimensional simplex, $\Delta^k=\{(x^0,\dots,x^k)\in \mathbb{R}^{k+1}|\sum_{i=0}^kx^i=1\}$, and let $\Omega^\bullet(\Delta^k)$ be the de Rham complex of smooth differential forms on $\Delta^k$ (as usual a differential form is smooth on $\Delta^k$ if it admits a smooth extension to an neighborhood of $\Delta^k$). It is well known, dating back at least to Poincare', that $\Omega^\bullet(\Delta^k)$ is an acyclic complex (in strictly positive degree).

Now consider the following graded subspace $\Omega^\bullet_{ctb}(\Delta^k)$ of $\Omega^\bullet(\Delta^k)$: for any point $p$ in $\Delta^k$, let $\Delta_p$ be the lowest dimensional simplicial subset of $\Delta^k$ the point $p$ belongs to and let $\pi_p$ the orthogonal projection on the linear subspace determined by the $\Delta_p$; and say that a differential form $\omega$ is "constant towards the boundary" if for any point $p$ in $\Delta^k$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\omega=\pi_p^*(\omega\vert_{\Delta_p})$ on $U$ (these differential forms are called "differential forms with sitting instants" in [Cech cocycles for differential characteristic classes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4735)).

Since the de Rham differential commutes with pullback (and restriction is a special case of pullback), it is immediate to see that $\Omega^\bullet_{ctb}(\Delta^k)$ is actually a subcomplex of $\Omega^\bullet(\Delta^k)$, and my question is: is $\Omega^\bullet_{ctb}(\Delta^k)\hookrightarrow \Omega^\bullet(\Delta^k)$ a quasiisomorphism? (equivalently, is $\Omega^\bullet_{ctb}(\Delta^k)$ acyclic in positive degree?). Or, in completely explicit terms, is it true that if $\omega$ is a closed differential form on $\Delta^k$ which is constant towards the boundary, one can find a primitive $\eta$ which is constant towards the boundary?

I've worked out the lowest $k$ cases by hand, and the answer is yes. For $k=1$ this is almost trivial and for $k=2$ it is just a bit more tricky, working inductively. Since no change in the homotopy typ happens as dimension of the simplex increases, I guess acyclicity of $\Omega^\bullet_{ctb}(\Delta^k)$ will be true for any $k$, but the inductive argument I have in mind gets more and more involved at every step, so that I rapidly loose control over it. On the other hand I am convinced that a clever application of Poincare' lemma (i.e. by choosing a contraction of the simplex to a point along a vector field which is orthogonal to the boundary and with a sink at the center of the simplex), but I'm not completely sure of this argument.

(do not hesitate to close this question if it is too localized)

Comment: How about using sheaves? Show that the sheaf of such forms is acyclic (no higher sheaf cohomology) and note that the usual Poincare lemma applies stalkwise.

Comment: Sure! proving stalkwise Poincare' lemma should be pretty immediate, and then the usual primary school spectral sequence does the job! Thanks a lot, Tom, I will blame myself for ages for having not thought of sheaves before asking! :) 

Comment: (and proving stalkwise Poincare' is not pretty immediate: it is completely and totally immediate. thanks again)

Comment: Finally, to show that the sheaf of such forms is acyclic it would suffice to prove that there exist partitions of the unity constant toward the boundary of the simplex (subordinate to a given open cover), which should not be hard. 

Comment: (and indeed it is not hard at all: one can mimic step by step the usual construction of partitions of unity on smooth manifolds, but with bump functions which are constant toward the boundary of the simplex)

Comment: I don't see how bump functions would do what you need them to -- how do you control variation of your forms without forcing them to go to zero?  Also, when you do something like remembering the boundary, you may very well lose homotopy invariance.  For instance, compactly-supported cohomology detects the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Concerning the homotopy invariance you are right, I expressed that very badly. What I meant is that I expected either a dramatic failure of acyclicity in every dimension or to have acyclicity: it would have been surprising to me to have acyclicity in dimension 1 and 2 and then a failure in dimension 3, and ven more surprising if the first counterexample would have occurred at an higher dimension. Clearly this is by no means a proof, just a mean I justified myself the conjectured acyclicity. (continues)

Comment: (continued) Concerning the role of bump functions, in my mind they were used to show that the sheaf of differential forms constant toward the boundary is a fine sheaf; isn't this correct?